# Extract the unique substrings at a given position range in a set of filenames

Tags: bash

I have a set of filenames (all of the same length) in a given dir and would like to find all the **distinct** substrings at a given position range in the filename (there will be many filenames with the same substring).

Specifically the substring I am interested starts at position 7 of the filename and goes
10 characters long

```
for file in *; do
      if [ -d "$file" ]; then
      file_basename=`basename $file`
      substr=${file_basename:7:10}
  done
```

I would like to write those unique substrings to either a file or a data structure that I can then loop through.

So the set of filenames

```
........12s456tyer..........
........12s436tyer..........
........12s456tyer..........
........12s436tyer..........
```

would lead to the 2 strings

```
12s456tyer
12s436tyer
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: assuming you've verified that `${file_basename:7:10}` gives you what you want, a quick/simple solution would be `for file in *; do ...;done | sort -u > output.file`

Comment: @markp-fuso You mean I have to echo the substring in each pass through the loop?

Comment: @user2175783 yeah, sorry ... got distracted and forgot the `echo` part

Comment: Is it files you want instead of directories, and do they have a common extension?

Comment: @konsolebox Yes the files at the root of the directory (there might be subdirs but I will skip those). The files  have different extensions but they always have the substring I am interested at the same location 7:10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use bash 4.0 or newer, you can create a unique associative array:

```
declare -A distinct_substrings=()
shopt -s nullglob # Prevent '*' from expanding to a literal '*'

for file in *; do
    if [[ -f $file ]]; then
        file_basename=${file##*/} # Not necessary if files are expanded from current dir.
        substr=${file_basename:7:10}
        distinct_substrings[$substr]=$substr
    fi
done

# Do stuff with "${distinct_substrings[@]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You would do it without looping:

```sh
printf '%s\n' * | cut -c 9-18 | sort -u >outputfile.txt
```

To do it only on files and exclude directories (requires bash):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s extglob
printf %s\\n *!(/) | cut -c 9-18 | sort -u >outputfile.txt
```

Comment: Wouldnt this include subdirs? I would like to skip subdirs, just the files.

Comment: @user2175783 Updated with method to exclude directories